# Scale down my external display

Tags: display, multi-monitor, elementary-os, monitors, resolution

I am using Elementary OS Hera.I have an external display (43 inch 1920x1080) and my primary display is my laptop (15.6 inch 1920x1080). When I connect the external display to my laptop, the font size is very large, and there is no option to scale down, and thus the large display is not utilised to the fullest. Is there any way I can solve this problem?

Comment: The real problem is that the two pixel densities are the same. Is the external display a TV screen?

Comment: Yes @JeremyBoden , the external display is a TV screen.